# Dirichlet's Theorem for Turan's Method of Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

This question concerns a special case of Turan's power sum, which looks reasonably straightforward.

Let $S(N,\nu)=\sum_{n=1}^N z_n^\nu,$ where all the $z_n$ are on the complex unit circle. Then, according to Gonek's paper *A Note on Turan's Method*, using Dirichlet's theorem on uniform approximation, one can show that there is some $\nu \in \{1,2,\ldots,6^N\},$ such that 
$$
\left \Vert \nu \arg \left(\frac{z_n}{2\pi}\right) \right\Vert \leq \frac{1}{6},\quad 1\leq n\leq N,
$$
where $||x||$ is the nearest distance from $x$ to an integer. This immediately implies that
$$
\max_{1\leq \nu \leq 6^N} |S(v,N)|\geq \frac{S(0,N)}{2}=\frac{N}{2}.
$$
How can one show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you want is this:

Given $$ reals $_$ (here $_=\arg \frac{z_k}{2\pi}$), a positive integer $q$ (here 6), we can find $1\leq \nu \leq q^N,\nu$ integral, s.t $\Vert v a_k\Vert\leq \frac{1}{q}$ and the proof uses the standard $N$ dimensional unit cube, the $q^+1$ points $(_1,..._)$,$0\leq \leq ^$ modulo 1, so in the cube (by using the pigeonhole principle when you divide each edge into $$ parts) you have $^$ compartments.

Armed with this result, you use the inequality $|\arg(w_k)| \leq \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$, where $arg$ is taken in $[-\pi, \pi]$, implies $\Re{w_k} \geq |w_k|\cos \theta$, so if say $|w_k|=1$, $|\Sigma{w_k}| \geq |\Re\Sigma{w_k}| \geq N\cos \theta $, where $N$ is the number of terms in the sum

$\Vert \frac{1}{2\pi}\arg{z_n^\nu}\Vert = \Vert\nu \arg \left(\frac{z_n}{2\pi}\right)\Vert$, so we can take $|\arg{z_n^\nu}| \leq \frac{\pi}{3}, \cos ({\arg{z_n^\nu}}) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and apply the above to deduce the inequality for precisely the $\nu$ given by Dirichlet which is bounded as noted

Comment: thanks. I am still unsure  where exactly $6^N$ is needed?

Comment: Dirichlet theorem that implies the existence of $\nu$  with that strong property about arguments requires it

Comment: thanks again for your patience. That the part I am unsure about. Could you provide a reference or a link to a good discussion of this if it's too involved to incorporate into the answer.

Comment: There is a good discussion in titchmarsh book on Riemann zeta - a pdf was linked here at some point - in chapter 8 about omega theorems and how dirichlet bound even exponential as it is allows more precise results while kronecker approximation which is needed for the inverse of zeta has no such

Comment: The statement you want is this: Given $N$ reals $a_k$ (here $a_k=\arg{\frac{z_k}{2\pi}}$), a positive integer $q$ (here $6$), we can find $1 \leq \nu \leq q^{N}, \nu$ integral, s.t $||\nu a_k|| \leq \frac{1}{q}$ and the proof uses the standard $N$ dimensional unit cube, the $q^{N+1}$ points $(ma_1,...ma_N), 0 \leq m \leq q^{N}$ modulo $1$, so in the cube, and the pigeonhole principle when you divide each edge in $q$ parts, so you have $q^{N}$ compartments

Comment: typo above - $q^N+1$ not $q^{N+1}$ obviously

Comment: do you mind if I copy this into your answer? That would fully answer the question and be easier to read.

Comment: sure no problem